# RGA Invalid Credentials

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I try to use the RGA Package (https://github.com/artemklevtsov/RGA) to get Data from Google Analytics core API.

```
authorize(
  client.id=options()$apiSecrets$id, 
  client.secret=options()$apiSecrets$clientSecret,
  cache=paste(getwd(),"daToken",sep="/")
)
```

So the cache is set to something like `/User/foo/bar/daToken`. I can see the file and everything works just right, I can access the data for now. After 30-60 minutes however the token expires it seems. Now on a new attempt there will be the error message `Error : client error: (401) Unauthorized Auth error: Invalid Credentials`

Why is the token not working any more? How to setup a longer live time? Plus: why is there an error and why does RGA don't try to get a new token?

Comment: This answer should be closed because https://github.com/artemklevtsov/RGA/issues/10#issuecomment-169042451

Answer (score -1):

Please read [Google Oauth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) documentation properly.

Access Token has lifetime of only 3600 seconds. After that you have to use Refresh Token to get new Access Token.

I have not used RGA package but I am sure there must be some mechanism to validate and refresh the Access Token.